# The server was taking too long to respond

Tags: hosting

I have hosted a site on iis manager and access it locally,but when i access the site on another machine it is giving the error that the server was taking too long to respond.So any suggestion for this that could help me out.

Comment: It could be that a firewall is blocking the request

Answer (score 0):

When your other machine is on LAN, you'll have to edit the Hosts file of each computer and add your domain name's entry resolving IIS web server IP address.Thus all LAN systems will know to which IP address to send the request to when your website is browsed.

Hosts file is located at path: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts